# What is the maximum size (row) of RecordInsertList/RecordSortedList in X++

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a requirement to improve performance of an D365FO excel import with one of our clients. The development was done by another developer. I'm considering using RecordInsertList to reduce the trips to the DB since the records being imported are so many (8000+). Currently the import is taking more than ever.

Now what I'm not sure is the size of the RecordInsertList/RecordSortedList, will accommodate the all these records once or another work around could help.

NB : I cannot use DMF since there are calculations that are done on-importing this file.

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question regarding the limit and memory. I would think you can still use DMF with some entity customization if needed too.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKwitny, I met the solution while I was still researching after posting to the forumn. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got something [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics/ax-2012/system-classes/gg923766(v=ax.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks).

There is no limit to the size of a `RecordSortedList` object, but they are completely memory-based, so there are potential memory consumption problems.

Therefore it is better to use [RecordInsertList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/dynamics.ax.application.recordinsertlist) which flushes records to the database as need be and thus uses constant memory.